# try-catch clause doesn't work with

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, exception, try-catch

When I feed an illegal value to "ID", I expect the "try" to fail and trigger the "catch" clause.

```
PreparedStatement ps1=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Table_1(id values(?)");    
try{
    ps1.setString(1,ID);
    ps1.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();
} catch(Exception EX){
    logger.error("Failed insert to table "+v.getId());
    logger.error(EX.getMessage(), EX);
    EX.printStackTrace();
    try{
        conn.rollback();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Cannot rollback connection");
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Instead, I get the following exception and the program terminates. It seems that the issue is connected to the "ps1.executeUpdate();" line.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Disallowed implicit conversion from data type ntext to data type varchar, table 'Table_1', column 'id'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

It's OK for me to get an exception, moreover, I would like to get an exception when the ID is illegal. However, I do not understand why the catch clause is not triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Table_1(id` theres a missing paranthesis?

Comment: The `prepareStatement()` is before the `try`/`catch` block.  Hence the error is not caught.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL string is not correct. do it like this:

```
insert into Table_1 (id) values(?)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    PreparedStatement ps1=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Table_1(id) values(?)");
    ps1.setString(1,ID);
    ps1.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();
} catch(Exception EX){
    logger.error("Failed insert to table "+v.getId());
    logger.error(EX.getMessage(), EX);
    EX.printStackTrace();
    try{
        conn.rollback();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Cannot rollback connection");
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the query has a bracket missing.
Correct query is:

```
PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Table_1(id) values(?)");
```

Secondly, I feel the logger is not initialized properly, so the functionality of **catch** block is not visible. However you are getting the error stack trace because of the **EX.printStackTrace()**

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid [SQL statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
conn.prepareStatement("insert into Table_1(id) values(?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not in try catch block, if it be the case then it should have been handled by try catch.
It was just a wrong sql statement. I recommend [Prepared statement tutorials](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface), as well as [Try catch tutorials](https://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block).

In the Meanwhile try following solution.

```
PreparedStatement ps1=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Table_1(id) values(?)"); 

try{
    ps1.setString(1,ID);
    ps1.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();
} catch(Exception EX){
    logger.error("Failed insert to table "+v.getId());
    logger.error(EX.getMessage(), EX);
    EX.printStackTrace();
    try{
        conn.rollback();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Cannot rollback connection");
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in First line..put ")" aside of id... bracket not closed